# Return a message if query was not successful

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using the following script to get the password of a user:

```
public function getHash($email) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.password')
        ->where('u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('email', $email)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
     ;
}
```

I call the method with:

```
var_dump($this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Users::class)
    ->getHash('mail@example.com'));
```

But I get the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

The reason why I get this notice, is because the string `mail@example.com` does not exist in my database.

I would simply like to know if the query was successful or not. Something like this:

```
if ($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->getHash('mail@example.com')) {
    echo 'All good';
}
else {
    echo 'There is an error';
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `getResult()` returns an empty array if no rows are found, so you can just check with `empty()`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky great, that helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: Empty array can be checked by usual `if - $a = []; if($a) // false`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your error is coming from a different part of code. As you are trying to access index `0` of an array that does not have this key.

For the no result check doctrine should throw a [NoResultException](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/Doctrine/ORM/NoResultException.html) when no results are found. (Or it does this for the `->getSingleResult()` function) You can simply catch this exception and handle it how you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use

```
->getOneOrNullResult();
```

and in controller check with an if statemant?

```
if(null === $result){}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method returns an Array of all matching results:
`->getResult()`
To check if there is no match:

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->getHash('mail@example.com');
if(empty($results){
    echo 'There is an error';
} else {
    $hash = $results[0];
}
```

This method returns one result or `null`:
`->getOneOrNullResult()`
To check if there is no match:

```
$hash = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->getHash('mail@example.com');
if(null===$hash){
    echo 'There is an error';
}
```

**Note:**
With `getOneOrNullResult()` you can assign the result directly to `$hash` and continue straight into your authentication logic comparing the the hash of the user-provided-password with the result. If there is no user `$hash` will be `null` so it will properly fail the comparison and you can handle just like the wrong password was entered. Keeping security in mind, if you confirm that there is no user with that email you are helping hackers because now they know not to waist time guessing passwords for that email.